# Marshalling List of Object without affecting existing list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, marshalling

I need to convert a list of object from java into xml files using JAXB.

**example:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
        <order_list>
           <order id = “1”/>
           <order id = “2”/> 
        </order_list>
```

without affecting it list of order in xml file , method to add one **order id** at a time to the **existing XML** in the above format.

the new order is always added at the **last child node** in the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations do not alter the `List` when marshalling an object to XML<sup>1</sup>.  The marshalled order will match the order of the items in the `List`.  The [`List.add(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) method will put the item at the end, but [`List.add(int, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) will let you specify the position.

<sup>1</sup><sub>An exception to this is something like a JPA implementation offering a `List` that lazy loads data as it is accessed.  In this case JAXB implementation would cause the list to change as the data is accessed.</sub>